# RecyclerView not populating on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to figure this problem out for quite a while now, but i just can't figure out what the problem is. The aim is to make a request to Songkick api (which is json), which will return the upcoming events of artist and populate it on the the fragment. The request works fine, but it doesn't come on the screen using recyclerView.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.artispot.fragments.FragmentEvents">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Adapter:

```
public class AdapterEvents extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterEvents.ViewHolderEvents> {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String cls = "TAG";
private ArrayList<Events> listEvents = new ArrayList<>();

public AdapterEvents(Context context){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setListEvents(ArrayList<Events> listEvents){
    this.listEvents = listEvents;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listEvents.size());
}

@Override
public ViewHolderEvents onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_events,parent,false);
    ViewHolderEvents viewHolder =new ViewHolderEvents(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

//create an object for each textview
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderEvents holder, int position) {
    Events currentEvent = listEvents.get(position);
    holder.DateTextView.setText(currentEvent.getStartDate());
//        + "--"+ currentEvent.getEndDate()
    holder.displayName.setText(currentEvent.getDisplayName());
    holder.Venue.setText(currentEvent.getVenue());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listEvents.size();

}

static class ViewHolderEvents extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView DateTextView;
    private TextView displayName;
    private TextView Venue;

    public ViewHolderEvents(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        DateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DateTextView);
        displayName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.displayName);
        Venue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Venue);
    }
}
```

}

and this part is from my fragment class:

```
 public void sendRequest(){
    // Formulate the request and handle the response.
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            getRequestUrl(),(String)null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse( JSONObject response) {
                   listEvents= parseJSONResponse(response);
                    adapterEvents.setListEvents(listEvents);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(request);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container,false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.List);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adapterEvents = new AdapterEvents(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterEvents);


    return view;
}
```

I have been on this for about a few days, and it's sort of frustrating because it's my project that is due in a week time. Any sort of help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have `View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_events, parent, false);` inside `onCreateViewHolder`

Comment: also you didnt call `setListEvents` anywhere, your listEvents is empty

Comment: Is there any error in `Logcat`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn, Nope no errors at all.

Comment: What's your `import` for `LinearLayoutManager`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn , import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager , do you think the xml properties could be the problem, as my xml is linearLayout?

Comment: What's `notifyItemRangeChanged`, why don't you call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn basically i followed a tutorial on youtube (Slidenerd videos), i had followed exactly the same steps as he carried out but mine is not working. we are both working with API requests and so i thought it might be good.

Comment: @JalalAtsakzai I could not see problem in your given codes, how do you add your fragment?

Comment: @Xcihnegn,  thank you for your efforts,  much appreciated.  The problem was in the custom_event xml,  where the orientation was set to vertical. Such silly mistake,  kept me stressed for days.